# What does this syslog message mean? (xhci_hcd buffer overrun on endpoint)

Tags: usb

My syslog is being flooded with this message:

```
kernel: [  547.728046] xhci_hcd 0000:0e:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event on endpoint
```

What does it mean? Through Google I found out, xhci_hcd has something todo with USB3. My USB3 Port seems to be working fine though. (Lenovo X220)

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I still have this problem and my syslog keeps getting very big because of this..